# Can I deploy a Windows Phone XNA app to a Samsung device?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, deployment, xna, samsung-mobile

I have created a Windows Phone 7 app using XNA 4.0. I can successfully deploy it to a Microsoft Phone (the phone I've used is running the Windows Phone 8 operating system) by connecting the phone to my computer with a USB cable and running the Windows Phone Application Deployment 8.1 tool (this tool allows me to deploy the .xap file to the phone, thus deploying the app). However, I now want to deploy the same app to a Samsung phone. Would I be able to do it using the same method (connect the Samsung phone to the computer and run the same deployment tool), or would I need to do this another way? If it is the latter, how could I go about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the OS on the Samsung device WinRT? Otherwise, you will probably not be able to. You may want to take a look at Xamarin/monogame and how to deploy them. Most importantly, did you try using the tool you have with the Samsung phone already?

Comment: @NahuelIanni I haven't had a chance to try it on the Samsung phone yet, but the operating system is Android 4.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone apps run on Windows Phones, Android apps run on Android. No way to deploy a Windows Phone app to an Android phone.

You can however port your XNA code to Monogame, should not be too hard and deploy it to Android then.